# ZF2 / Api call request throws The request must be chunked or have a content length

Tags: php, apache, api, http, zend-framework2

I try to deal with an external API and POST json data.

```
public function execute()
    {
        // ...
        try
        {
            $request = new Request();
            $request->setUri($this->getUrl());
            $request->setMethod('POST');
            $request->setHeaders($request->getHeaders()->addHeaders($this->getHeaders()));

            $client = new Client();
            $client->setOptions(['sslverifypeer' => false]);
            $client->setRawBody($this->getContent()); // content is JSON encoded

            $response = $client->dispatch($request);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            throw new Exception(Exception::UNEXPECTED_ERROR, $e->getMessage());
        }

        var_dump($response); exit;

        // ...
    }

protected function getHeaders()
    {
        return [
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            //'Content-Length' => strlen($this->getContent()),
            'Accept'        => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => Client::AUTH_BASIC . ' ' . base64_encode($this->username . ':' . $this->secret)
        ];
    }
```

If I don't send the `Content-length` header, this error is thrown `The request must be chunked or have a content length`

If I send it, the application thrown a `read timeout` error

All ideas will be appreciated

Comment: How big is whatever is returned by `$this->getContent()`?

Comment: `strlen($this->getContent())` returns 590

Comment: What's the API you're trying to connect to? Have you tried manually making the request with cURL or postman, or similar?

Comment: That's Saferpay API, I'll try with curl